# In Uno what happens if you play a "wild draw 4" card and then a "reverse" card on top of it?

Tags: uno

Does this mean that the player it reversed to has to pick up 4 cards instead of the next player it was originally intended for?

Or does this mean the next player picks up 4 cards and then you have another go as it reverses back to you?

I'm confused!

[image: wild draw 4 card]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In [standard Uno rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/42001pr.pdf) playing a Draw 2 or Wild Draw 4 forces the next player to draw the stated number of cards. You cannot respond to either of these with a Reverse.